# Will anyone be able to share a program or an example of solving a functional-differential equation in a Maple environment?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

Help me please. Give an example of a solution to the functional differential equation (FDE).
Will anyone be able to share a program or an example of solving a functional-differential equation in a Maple environment?

Comment: Do you mean like http://real.mtak.hu/29488/1/CogInfoCom_2013_submission_128.pdf?

Comment: Hello. looking for a certain algorithm (the method of research, the stability of the solution) or an example of solving directly the funcional-differential equation. Or any idea of ​​using computer technology to implement this topic.

Comment: The paper shows examples using a Maple program you can download. Maybe I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: thank my dear friend! this is what you need! However, in this article there is no program code of the main procedure (((maybe you have somewhere to eat?

Comment: http://www.uni-miskolc.hu/~matha/feqsolve9.mws

Comment: thank you very much, my dear friend !!! All the best and good luck!